# How to disable div tag in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to disable a **div tag** conditionally? Is there any property to disable the div tag

A solution to disable div tag in react js

Comment: what do you mean to do by disabling it ? I guess there is no `disable` prop for `div` ..

Comment: the attribute ```disabled``` only exists for elements that take some kind of user-input (like button, input, select etc.)

Comment: "Disable a div" doesn't make sense, a div is just a container for stuff. What **specifically** are you trying to do? Disable a bunch of buttons/inputs/etc. nested inside a div?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide a div you can try this :

```
function disableDiv(divId) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divId)
    div.style.display = 'none'
}
```

But there is no option to "disable" a div as you mentioned it...